# What is the difference between strategies and actions?

Tags: game-theory

I found in game theory these two concepts: *strategies* and *actions*. Both concepts are related to what the player will do but I can not make a distinction between the two concepts.

Comment: An intuitive answer : If a player has a strategy he/she has some (perhaps wrong) feeling what he/she does. An action can be done without a good reason why it was done. Maybe you mean "tactics" instead of "actions" ?

Comment: As an example, in a game with moves, an action is a move. A strategy is a rule for deciding which move to make in every possible situation..

Comment: I'm not very well versed in game theory, but I'm guessing that a strategy is a plan for which actions you are going to take.

Comment: For normal form games, there is an unfortunate habit of sometimes distinguishing pure versus mixed strategies by calling former actions and the latter strategies.  In this context a strategy is simply a probability distribution over actions.

Answer (score 3):

A strategy is a complete plan of action, specifying which action you would take in any possible contingency that might occur.

Intuitively, you choose actions "as you go", each time you need to make a decision, whereas a strategy got everything figured out before you start playing.